# Bison/Yacc use cases outside of programming languages?

Tags: regex, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I've been thinking about learning bison/yacc after reading some old Steve Yegge articles. Steve of course loves compilers and so recommends that people should learn them. He's given much other good advice on what skills to develop so I figured I'd take a look.

What I'm wondering is - what are the practical use cases for lex/flex/yacc/bison outside of constructing your own programming language? I'm sure there's an obvious use cases that I'm missing, but nothing comes to mind.

What kinds of problems can you more easily/stably solve with bison/yacc rather than parsing things with regexes?

Comment: Is it worth clarifying what you mean by language? For instance, if your question, does it mean "general-purpose programming language"? For surely the tools you mentioned are very useful even if you're "just" dealing with a small configuration, user-interaction, or specification language.

Comment: It's interesting to think of the coding of parsers for a language as constituting the "constructing" of the language. It's also useful to note that fully-constructed languages may also need parsers/compilers/validators built for them.

Comment: Combining Flex and Bison, you can create a [calculator](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_5.html#SEC27)--very easily.  Far more easily than if you tried to code an in-fix calculator via an all-purpose programming language (like Java or C).  In fact I once showed a friend that you can code a working in-fix calculator in about 20 minutes using Flex and Bison (obviously you have to know the syntax of each to do it this quickly).  If you know the structure of the input (_and_ the input is highly structured), you can do things very quickly with Flex/Bison.

Comment: Nick, I updated it to say "programming language" - but your comment seems to indicate that there are uses beyond this. :)

Comment: Yup, just about every interaction between computers and people or computers and computers (and even people and people), uses a language, and not all are programming languages, but all need to be parsed. For instance, html isn't a programming language, nor is xml, nor the phrases you can put into a google search to constrain to certain sites, avoid certain words, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kinds of problems can you more easily/stably solve with
>   bison/yacc rather than parsing things with regexes?

Big problems.

Keeping track of regexes for all the different, potentially nested lexical elements in a language can be daunting, and automation tools can make it more feasible, maintainable, shareable, etc.

> what are the practical use cases for lex/flex/yacc/bison outside of
>   constructing your own language?

Maybe the language already exists, but you want to implement a parser/compiler/validator for it. Possibly in new language or on a different platform than existing tools.

Comment: Right, those things make sense. I guess I'm wondering about those use cases such as "find addresses of this format in a bunch of text files" or "do some crazy input validation on this user-supplied string."

Comment: Ah, now you're asking, "if I have a problem that's perfectly suited for regexes, should I also consider flex/yacc, etc. as potentially good tools to apply?" I'd say generally no, if you can see how to solve the problem with regexes, it's probably not worth the extra oomph that automation provides.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, I've gotten quite far with regexes so far in my programming adventures. I guess I'm wondering where to draw the line between "okay, this regex-based parser is a beast" and "time to learn flex/bison/yacc/etc."

Comment: And also - how to recognize whether or not the problem in question is in fact "perfectly suited for regexes". I've seen a few instances where some sort of config file format or other file format needed to be defined, and somebody created their own format which then had to be parsed. I suppose a different answer might be "use JSON/XML" but sometimes we are handed a weird format and asked to parse it.

Comment: Perhaps a language spec that includes recursion? For instance, the fairly flat format of INI or CSV files is probably not too hard to handle with regexes manually, but if you need to handle something that can use triple quotes with single quotes inside, and includes eval, etc... it's probably time for a bigger hammer. In any case, the first problem you try to tackle with the new tool is going to be harder due to the learning curve, so the fact that you're this curious might just mean it's time to take on some toy problem and get the learning started!